# Corosync martian source messages on logs

Tags: corosync

We have a 2-node cluster, with IP addresses 10.150.5.179 (trpventus01) and 10.150.5.180 (trpventus02), and a virtual IP (ventusproxyVIP) on 10.5.150.181.
These nodes are Red Hat 7.2 with Corosync 2.3.4

We were getting 'martin source' messages in logs. This was happening because the netmask of this virtual IP was wrong, it was /24 and had to be /16. This provoked network issues, now it's fixed.

But we are still seeing these messages on our logs. Everything is working fine, but usually around 13:31 (not all days) these lines appear in our logs. We don't have any process triggering at this hour, so we are not sure why this is happenning.

At this hour, 13:31:11, the traffic is moved from trventus01 to trpventus02, and at 13:31:13 the traffic is moved back to the trpventus01 node again.

```
Apr 17 13:31:06 trpventus01 corosync[2351]: [MAIN  ] Corosync main process was not scheduled for 1092.4456 ms (threshold is 800.0000 ms). Consider token timeout increase.
Apr 17 13:31:06 trpventus01 corosync[2351]: [TOTEM ] A processor failed, forming new configuration.
Apr 17 13:31:06 trpventus01 corosync[2351]: [TOTEM ] A new membership (10.150.5.179:2012) was formed. Members
Apr 17 13:31:06 trpventus01 corosync[2351]: [QUORUM] Members[2]: 1 2
Apr 17 13:31:06 trpventus01 corosync[2351]: [MAIN  ] Completed service synchronization, ready to provide service.
Apr 17 13:31:13 trpventus01 corosync[2351]: [MAIN  ] Corosync main process was not scheduled for 5102.9751 ms (threshold is 800.0000 ms). Consider token timeout increase.
Apr 17 13:31:13 trpventus01 corosync[2351]: [TOTEM ] A processor failed, forming new configuration.
Apr 17 13:31:13 trpventus01 corosync[2351]: [TOTEM ] A new membership (10.150.5.179:2020) was formed. Members joined: 2 left: 2
Apr 17 13:31:13 trpventus01 corosync[2351]: [TOTEM ] Failed to receive the leave message. failed: 2
Apr 17 13:31:13 trpventus01 cib[3029]:  notice: crm_update_peer_proc: Node trpventus02[2] - state is now lost (was member)
Apr 17 13:31:13 trpventus01 crmd[3035]:  notice: Our peer on the DC (trpventus02) is dead
Apr 17 13:31:13 trpventus01 cib[3029]:  notice: Removing trpventus02/2 from the membership list
Apr 17 13:31:13 trpventus01 cib[3029]:  notice: Purged 1 peers with id=2 and/or uname=trpventus02 from the membership cache
Apr 17 13:31:13 trpventus01 cib[3029]:  notice: crm_update_peer_proc: Node trpventus02[2] - state is now member (was (null))
Apr 17 13:31:13 trpventus01 corosync[2351]: [QUORUM] Members[2]: 1 2
Apr 17 13:31:13 trpventus01 corosync[2351]: [MAIN  ] Completed service synchronization, ready to provide service.
Apr 17 13:31:13 trpventus01 attrd[3032]:  notice: crm_update_peer_proc: Node trpventus02[2] - state is now lost (was member)
Apr 17 13:31:13 trpventus01 attrd[3032]:  notice: Removing all trpventus02 attributes for attrd_peer_change_cb
Apr 17 13:31:13 trpventus01 attrd[3032]:  notice: Lost attribute writer trpventus02
Apr 17 13:31:13 trpventus01 attrd[3032]:  notice: Removing trpventus02/2 from the membership list
Apr 17 13:31:13 trpventus01 attrd[3032]:  notice: Purged 1 peers with id=2 and/or uname=trpventus02 from the membership cache
Apr 17 13:31:13 trpventus01 stonith-ng[3030]:  notice: crm_update_peer_proc: Node trpventus02[2] - state is now lost (was member)
Apr 17 13:31:13 trpventus01 stonith-ng[3030]:  notice: Removing trpventus02/2 from the membership list
Apr 17 13:31:13 trpventus01 stonith-ng[3030]:  notice: Purged 1 peers with id=2 and/or uname=trpventus02 from the membership cache
Apr 17 13:31:13 trpventus01 attrd[3032]:  notice: crm_update_peer_proc: Node trpventus02[2] - state is now member (was (null))
Apr 17 13:31:13 trpventus01 stonith-ng[3030]:  notice: crm_update_peer_proc: Node trpventus02[2] - state is now member (was (null))
Apr 17 13:31:13 trpventus01 crmd[3035]:  notice: State transition S_NOT_DC -> S_ELECTION [ input=I_ELECTION cause=C_CRMD_STATUS_CALLBACK origin=peer_update_callback ]
Apr 17 13:31:13 trpventus01 crmd[3035]:  notice: State transition S_ELECTION -> S_PENDING [ input=I_PENDING cause=C_FSA_INTERNAL origin=do_election_count_vote ]
Apr 17 13:31:13 trpventus01 attrd[3032]:  notice: Updating all attributes after cib_refresh_notify event
Apr 17 13:31:13 trpventus01 crmd[3035]:  notice: State transition S_PENDING -> S_NOT_DC [ input=I_NOT_DC cause=C_HA_MESSAGE origin=do_cl_join_finalize_respond ]
Apr 17 13:31:13 trpventus01 attrd[3032]:  notice: Recorded attribute writer: trpventus02
Apr 17 13:31:13 trpventus01 attrd[3032]:  notice: Processing sync-response from trpventus02
Apr 17 13:31:13 trpventus01 IPaddr2(ventusproxyVIP)[2302]: INFO: IP status = ok, IP_CIP=
Apr 17 13:31:13 trpventus01 crmd[3035]:  notice: Operation ventusproxyVIP_stop_0: ok (node=trpventus01, call=102, rc=0, cib-update=595, confirmed=true)
Apr 17 13:31:13 trpventus01 IPaddr2(ventusproxyVIP)[2359]: INFO: Adding inet address 10.150.5.181/16 with broadcast address 10.150.255.255 to device eno16780032
Apr 17 13:31:13 trpventus01 IPaddr2(ventusproxyVIP)[2359]: INFO: Bringing device eno16780032 up
Apr 17 13:31:13 trpventus01 IPaddr2(ventusproxyVIP)[2359]: INFO: /usr/libexec/heartbeat/send_arp -i 200 -r 5 -p /var/run/resource-agents/send_arp-10.150.5.181 eno16780032 10.150.5.181 auto not_used not_used
Apr 17 13:31:13 trpventus01 crmd[3035]:  notice: Operation ventusproxyVIP_start_0: ok (node=trpventus01, call=103, rc=0, cib-update=596, confirmed=true)
Apr 17 13:31:14 trpventus01 kernel: IPv4: martian source 10.150.5.181 from 10.150.5.181, on dev eno16780032
Apr 17 13:31:14 trpventus01 kernel: ll header: 00000000: ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 50 56 83 4e 49 08 06        .......PV.NI..
Apr 17 13:31:15 trpventus01 kernel: IPv4: martian source 10.150.5.181 from 10.150.5.181, on dev eno16780032
Apr 17 13:31:15 trpventus01 kernel: ll header: 00000000: ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 50 56 83 4e 49 08 06        .......PV.NI..
Apr 17 13:33:01 trpventus01 chronyd[1236]: Source 213.251.52.234 replaced with 193.145.15.15
```

It seems this is happening due to this: "Corosync main process was not scheduled for 1092.4456 ms (threshold is 800.0000 ms). Consider token timeout increase", at 13:31:06 followed by "Corosync main process was not scheduled for 5102.9751 ms (threshold is 800.0000 ms). Consider token timeout increase" at 13:31:11.

What could be the reason for this? Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: I'm seeing the same kind of problem. If I am not mistaken this has even led to STONITH inside the cluster. The obvious reason would be excessive load on the host, but that does not seem to be the case. Increasing he token timeout has helped, but I'd also like to understand the root cause.